# C++ - typeid(), used on derived class doesn't return correct type

Tags: c++, inheritance, typeid

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how inheritance works here, but here's my problem:

I have a class Option, and a class RoomOption that derives from it. I have another class Room which holds a vector of shared_ptrs. In main I add a RoomOption to that vector. Then, using typeid() I check the type, and it tells me its an Option. From what I've read, typeid is supposed to return derived types, and shared_ptrs dont cause slicing, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code:

Room.h:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Option> > options;
void addOption(shared_ptr<Option>);
shared_ptr<Option> getOption(int);
```

Room.cpp:

```
void Room::addOption(shared_ptr<Option> option){
    options.push_back(option);
}

shared_ptr<Option> Room::getOption(int i){
    return options[i];
}
```

main:

```
shared_ptr<Room> outside(new Room(0, "", ""));
outside->addOption(shared_ptr<RoomOption>(new RoomOption(0, "Go inside", hallway)));
cout<<typeid(player->getRoom()->getOption(0)).name().get()<<endl; 
//This line prints "class std::tr1::shared_ptr<class Option>
```

It occurs to me that maybe when adding or getting an Option, the RoomOption is casted as an Option due to the return/argument type. If that's the case then how am I supposed to store a vector of more than one type? Or am I getting this all wrong? =\

Comment: You're asking for the typeid of the shared pointer. Try to get the typeid of the thing the shared pointer contains.

Comment: use a dynamic_cast to check for types. Besides that your getting the typeid of the shared_ptr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all yor getting the typeid of the shared_ptr.

Then you should use [dynamic_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting) instead of typeid. E.g:

```
if (dynamic_cast<RoomOption*>(player->getRoom()->getOption(0).get()) != 0){
    cout << "Its a RoomOption!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the example. It's strangely difficult to find a simple example of how to check types with dynamic cast O.o

Comment: Notice though that a dynmic_cast is considered as a very expensive operation (since your code needs to lookup RTTI informations). Therefore, you shouldnt use it to frequently in time sensitive code.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann typeid also uses RTTI.

Answer (score 19):

The `typeid` works differently for polymorphic (for classes having at least one virtual function) and non-polymorphic types :

- If the type is polymorphic, the corresponding `typeinfo` structure which represents it is determined at run-time (the vtable pointer is commonly used for that purpose, but this is an implementation detail)
- If the type isn't polymorphic, the corresponding typeinfo structure is determined at compile time

In your case, you actually have a polymorphic class `Option`, but `shared_ptr<Option>` itsef isn't polymorphic at all. It basically is a container holding an `Option*`. There is absolutely *no* inheritance relation between `Option` and `shared_ptr<Option>`.

If you want to get the real type, you first need to extract the real pointer from its container using `Option* shared_ptr<Option>::get()` :

```
Option * myPtr = player->getRoom()->getOption(0).get();
cout << typeid(*myPtr).name(); << endl;
```

Or alternatively (it is exactly the same thing) :

```
Option& myPtr = *player->getRoom()->getOption(0);
cout << typeid(myPtr).name(); << endl;
```

Comment: I would remove the reference to the vtable pointer, it's a confusing implementation detail.

Comment: Note: you may also simply use `operator*` to get a reference to the underlying `Option` directly, rather than first using `get` and then using `*` on the pointer.

Comment: I wanted to make it clear that the real pointer was stored in the shared_ptr<> instance. Using a reference could let the OP think that shared_ptr<> is a pointer, whereas it's only a container trying to mimic the behavior of a pointer (and that's why typeid() was not working for him). I'll add this as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

The type of object a `shared_ptr<Option>` points to is part of its value, not its type. So this line of code is broken:

```
cout<<typeid(player->getRoom()->getOption(0)).name()<<endl;
```

You want this:

```
cout<<typeid(player->getRoom()->getOption(0).get()).name()<<endl;
```

Or perhaps:

```
cout<<typeid(*(player->getRoom()->getOption(0))).name()<<endl;
```

What `typeid` does is tell you the actual type of the thing you passed to it. You passed it a `shared_ptr<Option>`. It doesn't look inside the object to see what it contains.

Comment: Thanks. Still returns "Option*" though.