# Inheritance from std::exception class and typeid

Tags: c++

Why the inheritance from std::exception class gives the different output for the following code snippets:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base {};
class Derived: public Base {};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    throw Derived();
  }
  catch (const Base& ex)
  {
    std::cout << typeid(ex).name() << '\n';
  }
}
```

**Output**

> class Base

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base : public std::exception {};
class Derived: public Base {};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    throw Derived();
  }
  catch (const Base& ex)
  {
    std::cout << typeid(ex).name() << '\n';
  }
}
```

**Output**

> class Derived

Comment: You can add a virtual function to the `Base` class without inheritance from `std::exception` to make the code snippets behave identically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We call a class *polymorphic* if it declares or inherits at least one virtual function.

`typeid()` behaves differently for polymorphic and non-polymorphic classes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11484105/367273

Inheriting from `std::exception` makes your classes polymorphic (since `std::exception` has a virtual destructor and a virtual member function).

This explains the difference in behaviour between the two tests.