# How can I obtain dynamic type name in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

How can I obtain dynamic type name?

```
class O {
public:
std::string typename(){ return typeid(*this).name(); }
}

class C  : public O { /* ... */ }

O* varb = new C();
cout << O->typename(); // <--- return class O instead of class C
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: `typename` is a keyword.

Answer (score 4):

On my Linux/Debian/Sid/x86-64 system the file

```
// file raffa.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>

class O {
public:
    virtual std::string type_name() {
        return typeid(*this).name();
    }
    virtual ~O() {};
};

class C  : public O {
    int f;
public:
    C(int k) : O(), f(k) {};
    virtual ~C() {};
    /* ... */
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
    O* varb = new C(__LINE__);
    cout << varb->type_name() << endl; 
    delete varb;
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with

```
g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -Wall -O raffa.cc -o raffa
```

displays when running `./raffa`:

```
1C
```

The prefix `1` is probably because of [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling). See *carefully* answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/281818/841108) to unmangle it.

<sup>PS: in real life avoid raw pointers and be scared of [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), so don't copy my code verbatim without understanding these issues! Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) ...</sup>

Comment: 1) raw pointers owning memory. 2) leaks memory. Please do **not** post such crap code as an example. People **will** copy it in real projects.

Comment: The OP (not me) used some raw pointer. People copying that blindly without understanding pointer and memory allocation issues deserve what they should.

Comment: The OP also used `typename` as a member name, and you had no problem fixing that bug. Fix the leak, too!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Well *correct* the OP then. As David said, you had no problem fixing other bugs. And while I’m often vindictive myself, we’re here to teach and help, not allocate blame.

Comment: @DavidHammen & KonradRudoph: improved my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Declare your function returning typename as `virtual`. Otherwise `*this` will refer only to the part of `C` — `O` subobject. You can also google for polymorphism in C++.

**Edit.** As pointed out by @"Cheers and hth. - Alf", it's enough to declare *some* function as `virtual` to make a class polymorphic. And declaring a destructor `virtual` is a must for polymorphic base classes. But you still need to declare all the functions you will possibly reimplement as `virtual`.

Comment: A better approach is to make the destructor virtual. It's enough that the class is polymorphic (has *some* virtual member function). And the destructor is nice for that -- avoiding introducing an unintended customization point.

Answer (score 2):

[`typename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) is a reserved [keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) in C++!

Make `O::type_name()` [`virtual`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) to enable `C::type_name` to be invoked via an `O*`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class O {
public:
    virtual std::string type_name() { return typeid(*this).name(); }
    virtual ~O() {}
};

class C: public O {};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<O> varb { new C() };
    std::cout << varb->type_name();
}
```

[See it run!](http://ideone.com/2t8MgB)

Comment: and give O a virtual destructor.

Comment: A better approach is to make the destructor virtual. It's enough that the class is polymorphic (has some virtual member function). And the destructor is nice for that -- avoiding introducing an unintended customization point.

Comment: Good point, @Cheersandhth.-Alf. Making `type_name()` `virtual` looks more explicit to me, but you're right a `virtual` dtor would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Some errors in your code:

- First of all you cannot use **typename** as a custom name, it's a C++ keyword.
- Second, you cannot use

  ```
  O* varb = new C(); 
  cout << O->typename();
  ```

  since you're trying to dereference a class name and that makes no sense. You probably meant **varb->typename()** anyway.

To the typeid usage.. if you're trying to use typeid to return dynamically the name of the class a pointer is referring to (runtime), you should use something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class O {
public:
    virtual void vfunction() // Just one virtual function in the base to make the derived polymorphic
    {
        cout << "hello";
    }
};

class C  : public O 
{
    public:
    C() {};
};



int main() 
{
    // your code goes here

    O* varb = new C(); // Declare an O* pointer to C

    cout << typeid(*varb).name(); // This will print out "C", runtime info

    cout << typeid(varb).name(); // This will print out "O*"

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/K2RGd5

And keep in mind that a class needs to be polymorphic (that is, **to inherit from a base class with virtual functions**) in order for typeid to return the runtime class it is pointing to when dereferencing the pointer.

Some more information here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11484105/1938163

---

*Notice: in the code above, if you're using gcc, you might see different class names than the original you used.. that's custom-defined by gcc due to [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and if you want real code names to show up you should use something like*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h> // Needed to demangle in gcc
using namespace std;

class O {
public:
    virtual void vfunction()
    {
        cout << "hello";
    }
};

class C  : public O 
{
    public:
    C() {};
};



int main() {
    // your code goes here

    O* varb = new C();

    int status;
    // Demangle symbols
    cout << __cxxabiv1::__cxa_demangle( typeid(*varb).name(), nullptr, 0, &status ); << endl;
    cout << __cxxabiv1::__cxa_demangle( typeid(varb).name(), nullptr, 0, &status );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't obtain a nice human-readable type name in a portable way, without specifying each type name yourself.

However, with Visual C++ the `typeid::name` names are human readable, and with g++ they're not too bad.

So, simply change the current code

```
class O {
public:
std::string typename(){ return typeid(*this).name(); }
}

class C  : public O { /* ... */ }

O* varb = new C();
cout << O->typename(); // <--- return class O instead of class C
```

to

```
class O {
public:
    std::string type_name() const { return typeid(*this).name(); }
    virtual ~O() {}
};

class C  : public O { /* ... */ };

O* varb = new C();
cout << varb->type_name(); // <--- return class O instead of class C
```

where

- The function name `typename`, which is C++ keyword, was changed to `type_name`.
- The function was made `const`, so that it can be called on a `const` object.
- A virtual destructor was added to make the class **polymorphic** (a requirement for `typeid` to work in polymorphic way).
- Semicolon was added at the end of both class definitions.
- `O->` was changed to `varb->`: you can't dereference a class.

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands (but when you post a question you should better put the code to a compiler first!).